# Java Eclipse IDE ("For Java Developers" Version, Mac, 64-bit) Crashing Upon Launch

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

As soon as I double-click my Eclipse application (version stated in title), it crashes, and I receive the usual Mac problem report saying "Eclipse Quit Unexpectedly." The first time I downloaded it, I opened it and it worked fine, but when I quit it and reopened it, it crashed like this — I've tried reinstalling and deleting the previous edition, but to no avail. I'm running OS X El Capitan, 10.11, and Java 8, Update 20, and the most recent version of Eclipse — so I'm up to date on everything.

Here Is An Abbreviated Version of the Error Message:

```
Process:               eclipse [23861]
Path:                  /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
Identifier:            org.eclipse.platform.ide
Version:               4.5.1 (4.5.1.M20150904-0015)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           eclipse [23861]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-11-29 00:10:34.362 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4F4C24F6-3E2F-BC1B-B0CB-8B2DC6C5D233

Sleep/Wake UUID:       05764FB8-38E6-4010-BED2-53D9C217D124

Time Awake Since Boot: 270000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003c
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Comment: "Java 8, Update 20" is most definitely **not** an up to date version. Oracle's site offers update 66 for download.

Comment: Oh, shoot, suppose I should've known that (my computer said it was the "recommended" version, but not the "up to date" version). Nevertheless, I just updated and eclipse is still crashing...

Comment: Can you post the full error message, after that update was made, instead of an abbreviated one? And have you tried not running it under the /Applications folder?

Comment: @chackerian It sort of solved itself mysteriously for me after a couple of months when I deleted the app and reinstalled... So unfortunately I still dont know what the problem was 

Comment: ok. I had to reinstall twice now and so far no problems. I don't know if this error will come again.